# callback функция с циклом for внутри

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код, функция для перебора массива и функция для работы с элементом массива `-handler4`. Которая должна взять строку из массива и сделать из неё новую `abc`->`cba`; `123`->`321`
 При использовании цикла **for** в функции `handler4` происходит бесконечная итерация, почему так? Если использовать  `for(i=0;i<strings.length;i++)` то нет бесконечного цикла, но выводится только первый элемент массива. Почему так?

```js
let textArray = ["abc", 123];
function processArray(array, callback) {
  let value = "New value: ";
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    //console.log(i)
    value += callback(array[i]);
  return value;
}
 function handler4(element) {
  let backwards = "";
  let strings = element.toString();
  for (i = strings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) backwards += strings[i];
  console.log(element);
  return backwards + ", ";
}

    alert(processArray(textArray,handler4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас `i` - одна и та же глобальная переменная. Ее надо объявлять как локальную в каждой функции:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

...

for (var i = strings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) backwards += strings[i];
```

```js
let textArray = ["abc", 123];

function processArray(array, callback) {
  let value = "New value: ";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    //console.log(i)
    value += callback(array[i]);
  return value;
}

function handler4(element) {
  let backwards = "";
  let strings = element.toString();
  for (var i = strings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) backwards += strings[i];
  console.log(element);
  return backwards + ", ";
}

console.log(processArray(textArray, handler4))
```